# 12 hour time conversion

Tags: code-golf

## Challenge

Convert and print out a time in a 12-hour format. `HH:MM AM/PM`

#### Examples

Input:

- `'Fri Jun 30 2017 21:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'`
- `'Fri Jun 30 2017 00:10:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)'`
- `'Fri Jun 30 2017 12:10:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)'`
- `'Sat Jun 31 2018 8:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'`
- `'Fri Jul 01 2017 01:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'`
- `'Sat Apr 10 2020 09:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'`

Ouput:

- `9:14 PM`
- `12:10 AM`
- `12:10 PM`
- `08:06 AM`
- `1:14 AM`
- `09:06 AM`

#### Fine Points

- A zero before a one digit number **is okay**, no zero is also allowed. The following examples are **both allowed**:

  - `9:06 AM`
  - `09:06 AM`
- All tested years will be after `999` (each year will be **exactly** `4` digits)

## Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest solution in bytes wins
- [Standard Loopholes Apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- You may use functions as well as programs

Comment: Suggested test cases: `00:10:23 --> 12:10 AM` and `12:10:23 --> 12:10 PM`.

Comment: there we go. Feel free to edit if you see anything else I should change. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/105858/66104)

Comment: May we assume that the time is given in the timezone the program is being run in? (e.g. `'Fri Jun 30 2017 21:14:20 GMT-0400 (EDT)'` for me)

Comment: erm, June 31 doesn't exist. Is that accurate?

Comment: No zero is required. I will edit the challenge in an hour when I get home.

Comment: @pudility Thanks for clarifying. Removing close vote. I'll remove the downvote when you edit (which will unlock the vote)

Comment: Also, can the leading `0` be replaced by a space?

Comment: Sorry, But I am not sure I understand. Could you please elaborate? Also, I have edited the question, I hope this provides more clarity.

Comment: @pudility I mean if the output string can start with a space (instead of a zero) before a one digit number: `_9:14 PM` where `_` represents a space

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## JavaScript (ES6), 69 bytes

```
d=>new Date(d).toLocaleString(0,{hour:n='numeric',minute:n,hour12:1})
```

```js
f=
d=>new Date(d).toLocaleString(0,{hour:n='numeric',minute:n,hour12:1})
console.log(
  f('Fri Jun 30 2017 21:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Fri Jun 30 2017 00:10:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Fri Jun 30 2017 12:10:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Sat Jun 31 2018 8:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Fri Jul 01 2017 01:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Sat Apr 10 2020 09:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
)
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>58</s> 55 bytes

Assumes you are in the United States.

```
d=>new Date(d).toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:.. /,' ')
```

```js
f=
d=>new Date(d).toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:.. /,' ')
console.log(
  f('Fri Jun 30 2017 21:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Fri Jun 30 2017 00:10:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Fri Jun 30 2017 12:10:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Sat Jun 31 2018 8:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Fri Jul 01 2017 01:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Sat Apr 10 2020 09:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)')
)
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>81</s> 78 bytes

Answer before outputting a leading 0 in single-digit hours was made optional and test cases without leading 0s were added.

```
d=>([m,s]=d.slice(16).split`:`,`0${m%12||12}:${s} ${m<12?'A':'P'}M`.slice(-8))
```

```js
f=
d=>([m,s]=d.slice(16).split`:`,`0${m%12||12}:${s} ${m<12?'A':'P'}M`.slice(-8))
console.log(
  f('Fri Jun 30 2017 21:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Sat Jun 31 2018 08:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Fri Jul 01 2017 01:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)'),
  f('Sat Apr 10 2020 09:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)')
)
```

Comment: I was thinking about changing `${m>12?'P':'A'}M` to `${"AP"[m>12]}M`, but it doesn't work without casting the index to an integer (like with `|0`), which makes it the same length. Nicely golfed.

Comment: You can omit `,21` in the slice to save 3 bytes.

Comment: Returns 12:10 AM for `Fri Jun 30 2017 12:10:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)`. Should be PM. Changing `m>12` to `m>11` should fix it.

Comment: to save you 4 bytes: `d=>(new Date(d).toLocaleString(0,{hour:'numeric',minute:'numeric',hour12:1}))`

Comment: In fact, you could actually save 25 bytes with the following: `d=>(new Date(d).toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d+/,''))`

Comment: @RickHitchcock Fixed, thanks!

Comment: @pudility Added more answers based on your comments.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 66 bytes

```python
lambda s:`int(s[15:18])%12`+s[18:21]+'  APMM'[int(s[15:18])>11::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc/NCoJQEIbhvVfxbUKlgpnTnw0UCFEQCELuTMgo6UCp6GnR1ZvlKiia3cDDy0z5MJciV0222DfX9HY8pajloHPj1DFPhL3E7bE69NvNE8VJ3wb8MAjs@MMsmUVU0phzbWosEFtox15XGtt7jhFBEc@gWHgsirAJoiHNiOCEq8i1Bx3fpabj/OIeyBOa/uZd/Qrirk7/635ZgV/HtIrm3@tWYllZUUFD53g/JO9AWbUvI3O02zwB)

Comment: This fails for years that have less than 4 digits (although I'm unsure whether it has to work with those).

Comment: I think that is alright.

Comment: @notjagan it doesn't have to, it says so in the question.

Comment: @totallyhuman Whoops, sorry.

Comment: Can you change `int(s[15:18])>11` to `s[15:18]>"11"`?

Comment: Or even better: `s[15:]<"12"` and swap the `A` with the `P`

Answer (score 5):

## sh + coreutils, 22 bytes

```sh
date +%I:%M\ %p -d"$1"
```

(If seconds are allowed, then `date +%r -d"$1"` suffices.)

Comment: impressively few bytes! also well done

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 77 bytes

Assumes that the year has 4 digits.

```js
s=>`${([,,,h,m]=s.match(/\d./g),x=h%12||12)>9?x:'0'+x}:${m} ${'AP'[h/12|0]}M`
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>`${([,,,h,m]=s.match(/\d./g),x=h%12||12)>9?x:'0'+x}:${m} ${'AP'[h/12|0]}M`

console.log(f('Fri Jun 30 2017 21:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)')) // 09:14 PM
console.log(f('Fri Jun 30 2017 00:10:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)')) // 12:10 AM
console.log(f('Fri Jun 30 2017 12:10:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)')) // 12:10 PM
console.log(f('Sat Jun 31 2018 08:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)')) // 08:06 AM
console.log(f('Fri Jul 01 2017 01:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)')) // 01:14 AM
console.log(f('Sat Apr 10 2020 09:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)')) // 09:06 AM
```

Comment: Like above, I have found a smaller way to create and answer. Feel free to use my code, I don't think that it is really fare to answer my own question. `d=>(new Date(d).toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d+/,''))`

Comment: @pudility This would only work if your Locale is `en-US` and your timezone is `GMT-0700 (PDT)`. For instance, none of these assumptions are true for me.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 bytes

```
ÐU¯24)s8 r.³+SS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///CE0EPrjUw0iy0UivQObdYODv7/X92tKFPBqzRPwdhAwcjA0FzByNDK0MTKyEDB3TdE18DcwEBBI8AlRFMdAA)

12 bytes if we can assume that the time will be given in the computer's local time:

```
ÐU s8 r.³+SS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///CEUIViC4UivUObtYOD//9XdyvKVPAqzVMwNlAwMjA0VzAytDI0sTIyUAcA)

#### Mathy approach, 40 bytes

```
tG5 r"^.."_<C?+Z+B:°TnZ)%CÄÃ+" {"AP"gT}M
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=dEc1IHIiXi4uIl88Qz8rWitCOrBUblopJUPEwysiIHsiQVAiZ1R9TQ==&input=J0ZyaSBKdW4gMzAgMjAxNyAyMToxNDoyMCBHTVQtMDcwMCAoUERUKSc=)

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 36 bytes

```
16x3wC AMÇ^0ü^1[0-2]/12WrP
ç^ä:/é0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/39CswrjcWcHRV/pwe5zB4T1xhtEGukax@oZGEuFFAVyHl8cdXmKlf3ilwf//bkWZCl6leQrGBgpGBobmCkaGVoYmVkYGCu6@IboG5gYGChoBLiGaAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: 3136 7833 7743 2041 4d1b c75e 30fc 5e31  16x3wC AM..^0.^1
00000010: 5b30 2d32 5d2f 3132 1857 7250 0ae7 5ee4  [0-2]/12.WrP..^.
00000020: 3a2f e930                                :/.0
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 45 bytes

Answer improved thanks to manatwork

```
<?=(new DateTime($argv[1]))->format('h:i A');
```

First attempt:

```
<? $d=new DateTime($argv[1]);echo$d->format('h:i A');
```

Example usage through php CLI:

```
php d.php "Sat Apr 10 2020 09:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
```

This is my first golf try.

Comment: No need for variable `$d` and that way you can get rid of the explicit `echo`: `<?=(new DateTime($argv[1]))->format('h:i A');`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 43 bytes

```
Ḳ5ịṣ”:Ṗṁ3µV’%12‘Dµ1¦µV>11ị⁾PAµ3¦“0: M”żFṫ-7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AX0Agv9qZWxsef//4biyNeG7i@G5o@KAnTrhuZbhuYEzwrVW4oCZJTEy4oCYRMK1McKmwrVWPjEx4buL4oG@UEHCtTPCpuKAnDA6IE3igJ3FvEbhuastN////0ZyaSBKdW4gMzAgMjAxNyAwMDoxMDoyMyBHTVQtMDcwMCAoUERUKQ)

This is *superfluously too long*! That is, Jelly sucks at time manipulation.

EDIT: I'm even outgolfed by PHP!

Answer (score 0):

## Go, 103 bytes

```golang
func f(s*string){t,_:=time.Parse("Mon Jan 02 2006 15:04:05 MST-0700 (MST)",*s)
*s=t.Format("03:04 PM")}
```

Test here: https://play.golang.org/p/P1zRWGske-

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
5:24)16XO
```

Try it at [MATL online!](https://matl.io/?code=5%3A24%2916XO&inputs=%27Fri+Jun+30+2017+21%3A14%3A20+GMT-0700+%28PDT%29%27&version=20.1.1) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##hc4xC4JQFMXxvU9xNnMIzr2a2t0CUQikoDc05hhYhNjnf/mwLa39x/mfezt0/uq3pmks2eXoS@ejqr/h8HogIZSSQ8UkNSXqxm2Yk1ifShdHqy9JmtA0@S9Fl@S5HSYpQRZgYcx@1DtQPvXFn2Fz/@whoT4C7uY33w).

#### Explanation

```
5:24    % Push array [5 6 ... 24]
)       % Implicit input. Get characters at those positions. This
        % removes the first four characters with the day of the week
16      % Push 16
XO      % Convert to date string format 16, which is 'HH:MM PM'
        % Implicitly display
```

Comment: Can we have an explanation?

Comment: @totallyhuman Sure, thanks for reminding me. Edited. Basically the builtin `XO` does most of the work

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 39 bytes

```
#4è':¡¨`sD11›„APès<12%>0ìR2£R)Á… :M‚øJJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWgAl/8wNWFiMWX//yM0w6gnOsKhwqhgc0QxMeKAuuKAnkFQw6hzPDEyJT4ww6xSMsKjUinDgeKApiA6TeKAmsO4Skr//0ZyaSBKdW4gMzAgMjAxNyAyMToxNDoyMCBHTVQtMDcwMCAoUERUKQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 42 bytes

```php
<?=date_create($argv[1])->format('h:i A');
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt42JbEkNT65KBVIaagkFqWXRRvGaurapeUX5SaWaKhnWGUqOKprWv///9@tKFPBqzRPwdhAwcjA0FzByNDK0MTKyEDB3TdE18DcwEBBI8AlRBMA)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 145 bytes

```c#
namespace System.Linq{s=>{var d=DateTime.Parse(string.Join(" ",s.Split(' ').Skip(1).Take(4)));return d.ToString("h:mm ")+(d.Hour>11?"PM":"AM");}}
```

Full/Formatted version:

```c#
namespace System.Linq
{
    class P
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Func<string, string> f = s =>
            {
                var d = DateTime.Parse(string.Join(" ", s.Split(' ').Skip(1).Take(4)));

                return d.ToString("h:mm ") + (d.Hour > 11 ? "PM" : "AM");
            };

            Console.WriteLine(f("Fri Jun 30 2017 21:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)"));
            Console.WriteLine(f("Fri Jun 30 2017 00:10:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)"));
            Console.WriteLine(f("Fri Jun 30 2017 12:10:23 GMT-0700 (PDT)"));
            Console.WriteLine(f("Fri Jul 01 2017 01:14:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)"));
            Console.WriteLine(f("Sat Apr 10 2020 09:06:20 GMT-0700 (PDT)"));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata), 41 [bytes](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata/wiki/Code_page)

```
::18⊢3⊣⇆15⊢3⊣i11>"  APMM"⇆⊢2⟛↔15⊢3⊣i12%s#
```

### Explanation

WIP